Exception encountered: Unrecognized keyword arguments: ['batch_shape']
when i tried to load keras model, i encountered this weird error:
here is my code:
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/kaggle/input/iyntmodel/vgg19.keras')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_layer.py:868, in Layer.from_config(cls, config)
    867 try:
--> 868     return cls(**config)
    869 except Exception as e:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/input_layer.py:153, in InputLayer.__init__(self, input_shape, batch_size, dtype, input_tensor, sparse, name, ragged, type_spec, **kwargs)
    152 if kwargs:
--> 153     raise ValueError(
    154         f"Unrecognized keyword arguments: {list(kwargs.keys())}"
    155     )
    157 if sparse and ragged:

ValueError: Unrecognized keyword arguments: ['batch_shape']

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 1
----> 1 model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/kaggle/input/iyntmodel/vgg19.keras')

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_api.py:254, in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode, **kwargs)
    249     if kwargs:
    250         raise ValueError(
    251             "The following argument(s) are not supported "
    252             f"with the native Keras format: {list(kwargs.keys())}"
    253         )
--> 254     return saving_lib.load_model(
    255         filepath,
    256         custom_objects=custom_objects,
    257         compile=compile,
    258         safe_mode=safe_mode,
    259     )
    261 # Legacy case.
    262 return legacy_sm_saving_lib.load_model(
    263     filepath, custom_objects=custom_objects, compile=compile, **kwargs
    264 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py:281, in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    278             asset_store.close()
    280 except Exception as e:
--> 281     raise e
    282 else:
    283     return model

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_lib.py:246, in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    244 # Construct the model from the configuration file in the archive.
    245 with ObjectSharingScope():
--> 246     model = deserialize_keras_object(
    247         config_dict, custom_objects, safe_mode=safe_mode
    248     )
    250 all_filenames = zf.namelist()
    251 if _VARS_FNAME + ".h5" in all_filenames:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/serialization_lib.py:728, in deserialize_keras_object(config, custom_objects, safe_mode, **kwargs)
    726 safe_mode_scope = SafeModeScope(safe_mode)
    727 with custom_obj_scope, safe_mode_scope:
--> 728     instance = cls.from_config(inner_config)
    729     build_config = config.get("build_config", None)
    730     if build_config:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/sequential.py:466, in Sequential.from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)
    464 for layer_config in layer_configs:
    465     use_legacy_format = "module" not in layer_config
--> 466     layer = layer_module.deserialize(
    467         layer_config,
    468         custom_objects=custom_objects,
    469         use_legacy_format=use_legacy_format,
    470     )
    471     model.add(layer)
    473 if (
    474     not model.inputs
    475     and build_input_shape
    476     and isinstance(build_input_shape, (tuple, list))
    477 ):

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/serialization.py:276, in deserialize(config, custom_objects, use_legacy_format)
    268 if use_legacy_format:
    269     return legacy_serialization.deserialize_keras_object(
    270         config,
    271         module_objects=LOCAL.ALL_OBJECTS,
    272         custom_objects=custom_objects,
    273         printable_module_name="layer",
    274     )
--> 276 return serialization_lib.deserialize_keras_object(
    277     config,
    278     module_objects=LOCAL.ALL_OBJECTS,
    279     custom_objects=custom_objects,
    280     printable_module_name="layer",
    281 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/serialization_lib.py:609, in deserialize_keras_object(config, custom_objects, safe_mode, **kwargs)
    602         if isinstance(module_objects[config], types.FunctionType):
    603             return deserialize_keras_object(
    604                 serialize_with_public_fn(
    605                     module_objects[config], config, fn_module_name
    606                 ),
    607                 custom_objects=custom_objects,
    608             )
--> 609         return deserialize_keras_object(
    610             serialize_with_public_class(
    611                 module_objects[config], inner_config=inner_config
    612             ),
    613             custom_objects=custom_objects,
    614         )
    616 if isinstance(config, PLAIN_TYPES):
    617     return config

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/serialization_lib.py:728, in deserialize_keras_object(config, custom_objects, safe_mode, **kwargs)
    726 safe_mode_scope = SafeModeScope(safe_mode)
    727 with custom_obj_scope, safe_mode_scope:
--> 728     instance = cls.from_config(inner_config)
    729     build_config = config.get("build_config", None)
    730     if build_config:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_layer.py:870, in Layer.from_config(cls, config)
    868     return cls(**config)
    869 except Exception as e:
--> 870     raise TypeError(
    871         f"Error when deserializing class '{cls.__name__}' using "
    872         f"config={config}.\n\nException encountered: {e}"
    873     )

TypeError: Error when deserializing class 'InputLayer' using config={'batch_shape': [None, 299, 299, 3], 'dtype': 'float32', 'sparse': False, 'name': 'input_layer_1'}.

Exception encountered: Unrecognized keyword arguments: ['batch_shape']


it might be the model you loaded is trained with tensorflow version different from the loading environment.
refer https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/66381
